# Scala trait: Cannot get abstract parent trait values by passing values in the child

Tags: scala, traits, mixins, class-hierarchy

This example is a mock-up of a bigger problem I'm trying to solve. The hierarchy at the top is the abstract trait CarFamily, then there are 3 abstract traits extends from CarFamily, namely Honda, Civic, and Volvo. My goal is to be able to call the carModelStatement for each child trait in an instance that extends from these 3 traits.

However, as you can see the results, the statements all return "The model of the car is null". So the val volvo, honda, civic didn't get passed to the  I'm new to Scala. Would like to know what I'm missing or if there is another design to get what I want. Thanks!

```
trait CarFamily {
val carModel: String
def carModelStatement: String = s"The model of the car is ${carModel}"
}

trait Honda extends CarFamily {
val honda: String
override val carModel: String = honda
def hondaModelStatement : String = carModelStatement
}

trait Civic extends CarFamily {
val civic: String
override val carModel: String = civic
def civicModelStatement : String = carModelStatement
}

trait Volvo extends CarFamily {
val volvo: String
override val carModel: String = volvo
def volvoModelStatement : String = carModelStatement
}

object allModels extends Volvo with Civic with Honda {
val volvo = "Volvo X3"
val civic = "Civic Family"
val honda = "Honda Extreme"

}

allModels.volvoModelStatement //res1: String = The model of the car is null
allModels.civicModelStatement // res2: String = The model of the car is null
allModels.hondaModelStatement  // res3: String = The model of the car is null
```

Comment: I'm afraid that when you get this to work, you will find that it doesn't quite do what you might be expecting.

Answer (score 0):

So the root cause of the problem is that you have an abstract `val` in your root trait. `val`s get initialized in order (not all at once), and this order may at times be surprising - e.g. you'll see `null`s where you wouldn't expect them if you override these `val`s or have a forward reference from anywhere in the same class.

So the rule of thumb to avoid such problems is simple: *always use `def` for abstract members*.

This rule adds an additional benefit of being flexible in the type of member to use to implement/override these fields: you can extend a `def` with a `def`, `val`, `var` or `lazy val` (the latter being very useful at times).

Further, I tried to grasp what you're trying to achieve with this code and I'm thinking that your understanding of multiple inheritance in Scala is probably wrong. Even if you use `def` in your root trait, there will be just one value of `carModel` and `carModelStatement`, respectively, inside `allModels` - yielding identical strings for everything that depends on this property.

Comment: This rule of thumb is a common misunderstanding. Changing abstract `val` to `def` won't have any effect, what matters is the implementation being a `val` or depending on `val`s of the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can 'store' the value in a trait member, in the way that you are trying to.

This works though:

```
trait CarFamily {
  def carModelStatement(carModel: String): String = s"The model of the car is ${carModel}"
}

trait Honda extends CarFamily {
  val honda: String
  def hondaModelStatement : String = carModelStatement("honda")
}

trait Civic extends CarFamily {
  val civic: String
  def civicModelStatement : String = carModelStatement("civic")
}

trait Volvo extends CarFamily {
  val volvo: String
  def volvoModelStatement : String = carModelStatement("volvo")
}

object allModels extends Volvo with Civic with Honda {
  val volvo = "Volvo X3"
  val civic = "Civic Family"
  val honda = "Honda Extreme"

}

allModels.volvoModelStatement 
allModels.civicModelStatement 
allModels.hondaModelStatement
```

Output:

```
res0: String = The model of the car is volvo
res1: String = The model of the car is civic
res2: String = The model of the car is honda
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced a similar situation. using `this.` solves this problem.

```
trait CarFamily {
var carModel: String = "test" //assign some string and change val to var
def carModelStatement: String = s"The model of the car is ${carModel}"
}

trait Honda extends CarFamily {
this.carModel=  "honda" //pass the actual string value
}
```